# {enc28j60} Is the 50ppm crystal good enough

Tags: ethernet, crystal, precision

I have some 25MHz 50ppm crystals but I am not sure if they are good enough to be used with ENC28J60.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information that critical to the usage of the chip is is always in the datasheet. If it can be summed up in a couple of numbers and you can't find it in the main table of specifications (if there is one at all), then it's usually under the "Electrical Characteristics" section near the end of the datasheet. That is exactly where it is in this case, under that section on page 81, Table 16-2.

Comment: I was looking in the Oscillator section. Did not check that table.

Comment: Yeah, if it's a weird extraneous technical-sounding number, you wouldn't find it in the mainstream text section of the document. It'd be hidden under electrical characteristics. The same is true for microcontroller datasheets. Any datasheet for a part that can't be described by just a table of specs that has a lot of text about how to use the part.